# Get GitHub User by ObjectID from SCIM (Azure AD)

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3, github-app

I have a Github App and I would like to look up a Github User. We have our organization connected to our corporate Azure AD.

Is it possible to find a Github User based on an ObjectId or UPN from AzureAD?

I've tried this API https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/scim#get-scim-provisioning-information-for-a-user and gave my app "read-only on members" (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps#permission-on-members), but it doesn't show anything.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried `/scim/v2/organizations/MYORG/Users` but it gives me "403 Resource not accessible by integration". Which permission is needed?

Comment: is it resolved? I am also trying but getting below error - SCIM is not enabled for this organization: SAML SSO is configured on the enterprise account.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the AAD ObjectId would map to SCIM externalId. If GitHub supports it, GET /Users?filter=externalId eq "ObjectIDValue" or GET /Users?filter=userName eq "user@domain.com"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but it doesn't seems to work. Can you give a better example

Comment: If it doesn't work because of the permissions related stuff you mentioned above, that's something I'm not familiar with. I provided the filters you'd use in a SCIM GET call. If you're getting the "403 Resource not accessible by integration" - that sounds like you may not be able to manage that user via SCIM? Probably worth opening a support case with GitHub to understand what is possible and what permissions are required.